# Open and closed elements in a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, user-input, nested-loops

I am trying to create a grid using a  2D array that has open and closed elements. The open elements will be represented by a `.` and closed elements will be represented by `*`.

In the open elements, letters representing colors are able to be placed in each element. A letter will be placed one at a time. When a letter is placed inside the open element which is next to a closed element, the closed element will then become open.

The player can then place a letter in this new open element on their next move. No letter should be allowed to be placed in any closed element. This will continue to repeat.

The image attached below shows a better visual understanding.

I have created a 2D array using a nested for loop. Within this nested loop I have used an if statement to make the first column open with `.`.

I have been trying to create these open and closed elements outside of this nested for loop however I can only seem to access one element at a time, however I am trying to access multiple.

I am not looking for people to send me code or anything but I am aksing for help in understanding how to create these open and closed elements.

```
public class MatrixGrid {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Move row?");
        int r = StdIn.readInt();
        System.out.println("Move Colomn?");
        int c = StdIn.readInt();
        int m =8;
        String p = "G";
        
        
        String[][] grid = new String[m][m];
            
        for (int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {
            
            for (int j=0; j<grid[i].length; j++) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    grid[i][j] = "*";
                } else {
                    grid[i][j] = ".";
                }
                grid[r][c] = p;
                    
                StdOut.print(grid[i][j]);
                    
            }
            StdOut.println();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image showing the progression of open and closed elements in a 2D array]

Answer (score 0):

With the way you access the elements of the nested array (`grid[i][j]`) you can only access one element at a time. You could also access the complete sub-array `grid[i]` - that would be a one-dimensional array: `String[]`.

To access multiple elements of the multi-dimensional array (e.g. around the entered position of the player, `r` and `c`) you will have to use either loops or multiple single operations, like with `grid[r-1][c]`, `grid[r][c+1]` and so on, to reach the neighbours. Take care that you do not exceed the array boundaries (but you have to prepare for special cases at the edges of the grid anyways).

Otherwise you might be interested to do matrix operations, but that is a completely new topic and probably too much for here. (It is also not directly supported by core Java, you would have to use extra libraries.)

Comment: What happens if it's a  multidimensional array that changes size. So I won't know what the size is going to be each time. Surely I can't code those elements individually?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "that changes size"? How would an array change its size without you, the developer, implementing that? You always can use the `.length` property of an array to determine it's size, a multi-dimensional array is just an array of arrays. (so each sub-array could have it's individual length, it's up to the developer to support that or not)